# How to add spaces after a certain number of lines?

Tags: python

Currently the string I want to change looks like `ABCDEFGHIJKL`

I'm looking to change it to `AB CDEF GHIJ KL`
checked around but I was only able to find help on entering spaces at regular intervals.

Comment: Are there any rules after how many chars you want to insert a space?

Comment: Change your string to `"  ABCDEFGHIJKL  "` with 2 spaces before and after. Use the reference you already found to add spaces after every 4th. Then call `.strip()` on the result.

Comment: Do you mean after a certain number of **spaces**? Also, the spaces in what you want to change it are not regular.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

With no particular rules defined, I can only see the following approach at the moment:

```py
string_with_spaces = f"{string[:2]} {string[2:6]} {string[6:10]} {string[10:]}"
```

Based on what you have said in your question, you are *not* interested in adding spaces at *regular intervals*.

Comment: Don't try to guess what the OP meant, as it's question clearly lacks details. Just wait for him to clarify himself before answering.